# How can I convert any numerical value into alphabets in C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, visual-c#-express-2010

I am beginner to programming and c# , I want to convert a value which has minimum 6 digits into alphabetic form which also have the same number of Alphabets.I do not want to make it simple for user who have numerical value but he will not be able to guess its alphabetic value.that is the code i am trying to use.

```
   string a = input.Text;
   string temp = "ABCDEFGHIJKL";
   string ans = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
   ans += temp[a[i] - 48];
   output.Text = ans;
```

Comment: "I want smth from smth"...please be more accurate. Samples of input and output data and code which you tried would be great.

Comment: I didn't understand the question, can you post some examples?

Comment: @Fischermaen i think this answers that **not to be able to guess its alphabetic value** :)

Comment: I just want to convert numerical value into alphabetic value e.g input value =673422, output value = ACDNMQ

Comment: 673422 -> GHDECC Of not? Would you like to ACDNMQ why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a method for you, solving what I've understand your problem is:

```
public string ConvertNumToAlpha(string numbers)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        result += Convert.ToChar(int.Parse(numbers.Substring(i, 1)) + 64);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And another "high-sophisticated encrypt" method:

```
public string EncryptNum(string numbers, string encryptString)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        result += encryptString.Substring(Math.Min(int.Parse(numbers.Substring(i, 1)), encryptString.Length) - 1, 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```